# Will operating system memory change after jvm GC?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

This is jvm memory heap
[image]

This is system memory
[image]

Comment: [Garbage Collection in Java – What is GC and How it Works in the JVM](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/garbage-collection-in-java-what-is-gc-and-how-it-works-in-the-jvm/)

Comment: It depends on many factors, including the JVM, GC settings, actual memory usage, etc. In general most implementations try not to.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite certain that JVM is hosted by underlying OS.
For example, Ubuntu, Parrot, Windows 10, etc.

This can help you visualize it: [This how JVM looks on different OS's.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKXdP.jpg)

You may also know how JVM architecture looks like: ([This is how JVM architecture looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI7gp.jpg))

**Now does JVM's memory usage has anything to do with operating system's memory usage?**

No. Out of total main memory JVM uses memory for its various purposes, heap memory most know of them. This means, total main memory usage changes but not the memory used by the particular OS (as OS's have their own jobs to look after).

Regards.